# How to set text for ApplicationBarMenuItem programatically wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created the ApplicationBarMenuItem from xaml but i want to set the menuitems text programatically. so i am doing like below:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">           
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuDelete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuEditView" Click="Edit_Click"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuFilter" Click="Filter_Click"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

for set the text i am doing like:

menuDelete.Text = "Delete";

But it is giving null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue.

For first button(menuDelete) i did like below and it is working for me.

```
ApplicationBarMenuItem delete = ApplicationBar.MenuItems[0] as ApplicationBarMenuItem;

if (delete != null)
            {
                delete.Text = MainStrin.delete_txt;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine too:

```
((ApplicationBarMenuItem)ApplicationBar.MenuItems[0]).Text = "text";
```